# ID doesn't exist although it does

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project for class, and I have a dropdown box with the id of "idSelect." But when I try to grab the value of the dropdown box into a variable, it says that `idSelect` isn't defined.

I tried changing the name of the id, but the same thing happened. If I try to `console.log(idSelect.value)`, it shows up as whatever I have selected, but it still shows an error that `idSelect` is not defined.

This is in the head tags & script tags

```html
var selectedHero = idSelect.value;
```

This is in the body tags

```html
Change your avatar:
    <select id="idSelect">
        <option>Batman</option>
        <option>Spider-Man</option>
        <option>Iron Man</option>
        <option>Superman</option>
        <option>Wolverine</option>
    </select>
```

The variable `selectedHero` should store whatever the player has selected in the dropbox such as "Iron Man" or "Superman," but instead in the Inspect element all it says is this:

```
Monster Project (BLANK).html:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: idSelect is
not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/chim%20chimoi/Desktop/Ifra/APCOMSCI/Monster_Project_HOME/Monster%20Project%20(BLANK).html:22:22
```

This worked before and I didn't change anything, but when I ran it again this error just started popping up.

Comment: Maybe you'll provide code of how you define it?

Comment: @Anthony: there's really no need to. The HTML spec permits so called [named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object) which means that accessing DOM elements as globals (props of the `window`) is perfectly valid.

Comment: You need to show your actual JS code. We could sit here and guess, but why?

Comment: If your code is in the head, and you're not delaying its execution until the body (or at least that element) is loaded, then the element does not exist at the time of execution.

Comment: If your `console.log(idSelect.value)` works then you're probably running it in the console, or in some other location relative to the HTML.

Comment: please show your complete js code. and is your js and html in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a HTML's id into Javascript, and in Javascript there's no such variable idSelect being declared, e.g.:

```
var idSelect;
```

But even if you declare it in Javascript, the way to pass the HTML's value into Javascript is not correct.

If you want to keep the same variable name, you can do this:

```
var idSelect = document.getElementById('idSelect').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there was a variable "idSelect" which does not exist, or is not accessible at the point you are referencing it.

Try making it global:

```js
<script>
    window.idSelect = document.getElementById('idSelect');
</script>
```

or reference it like this every time you need it:

```js
<script>
    var idSelect = document.getElementById('idSelect');
    var selectedHero = idSelect.value;
</script>
```